# How to pass value from Jquery to Asp.net Code Behind File?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have radio button and i stored some value on each radio button

```
$(document).on('change', '.vEditTamplateId', function ()
{
        var vpath = "";
        $(".vEditTamplateId").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked") == true) {

                vpath = $(this).attr('idd');
                $('input[id$=hdnEmpName]').val(vpath);
            }
        })

});
```

This is it's code..

I have used this asp.net server side control

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnEmpName" runat="server" />
```

Now to use code behind i use

```
            string vPath = hdnEmpName.Value;
```

I always get null value in this

Please suggest me proper suggestion..

Comment: Can you show the markup of elements with css class "vEditTamplateId", over which you iterate? Also, how is postback done?

Answer (score -2):

### Simple Way

```
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "AutoSearchTest.asmx.cs/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('/')[0],
                                val: item.split('/')[1]
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#lblUserId').text(ui.item.val);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> GetAutoCompleteData ( string username )
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ "ERP_ConnectionString" ].ToString() ) )
    {

        string query= "SELECT Code, [Description] from tablename Where Compcode = '01' and Description LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'";
        using ( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( query, con ) )
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@SearchText", username );
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while ( dr.Read() )
            {
                result.Add( string.Format( "{0}/{1}", dr[ "Code" ], dr[ "Description" ] ) );
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation why this is the correct solution? The code could be excellent, but explaining why might help the original question.

Comment: In what way does this relate to the OP's question?

Comment: It is just to send client side value to server side for a help

Comment: Clearly the OP isn't trying to use AJAX, just trying to add the value to a hidden field. Posting a completely unrelated example is not helpful.